# Why was this answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, homework-and-exercises, close-reasons, deleted-answers

[My answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/692997/78922) to a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/692994/78922) was deleted under homework policy. The question didn't seem like homework. It was a genuine doubt why the user was getting a wildly different answer than the solution.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am not contesting that my answer be undeleted. Just wanted to be aware so that I am careful next time onwards.

Comment: *[Can doubt sometimes mean question?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429)*

Answer (score 2):

In my eyes, it's the "check-my-work" part of the policy that applies here - technically, it's the *work in the linked video* were supposed to scrutinize (which additionally makes the question prone to link rot if the video vanishes), but the essence is the same: The question asks about the correctness of a specific calculation, and your answer points about the specific part of that calculation that is wrong.

I could understand if people disagree with this interpretation - if the question is reopened, please flag the answer so it can be undeleted.